# Обертка над boost::signals

Tags: c++, boost

Недавно начал изучать boost. Обратил внимание на сигналы/слоты. Подумал, что было бы неплохо написать функцию connect для облегчения синтаксиса - без необходимости постоянно вызывать boost::bind.
Аргументами функции являлись бы - название слота, указатель на объект, указатель на сигнал и число аргументов у сигнала и слота.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    //Функция соединения
    template< class A1, class M, class T, typename... Args, class B>
    static boost::signals2::connection connect( M T::*f, A1 a1, B &connection, int num)
    {
            return connection.connect(getBind(f, a1, _1, _2));
    }

    template< class A1, class M, class T, typename... Args >
    static boost::function<M> getBind( M T::*f, A1 a1, Args&& ...arg) {
        return boost::bind(f, a1, boost::forward<Args>(arg)...);
    }
};

class OtherClass
{
public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int, int)> myConnection;
    void start() {
        myConnection(2, 2);
    }
};

class MyClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void myFunc(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "hello " << a << " " << b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyClass *cl = new MyClass;
    OtherClass *myOtherClass = new OtherClass;

    BaseClass::connect(&MyClass::myFunc, cl, myOtherClass->myConnection, 2);

    myOtherClass->start();

    return 0;
}
```

В таком варианте оно компилируется и работает только если не менять аргументы у сигнала и слота. А мне бы хотелось создать универсальный вариант.
Дополненный код функции connect:

```
static boost::signals2::connection connect( M T::*f, A1 a1, B &connection, int num)
    {
        if (num == 1)
            return connection.connect(getBind(f, a1, _1));
        if (num == 2)
            return connection.connect(getBind(f, a1, _1, _2));
    }
```

И вот так оно не компилируется, даже если не менять аргументы - вроде как если num равно 2, то должен был выбраться нужный вызов bind.

Ошибки следующие:

> C:\Libs\boost_1_67_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp:75: ошибка: C2825: 'F': must
>   be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
>   C:\Libs\boost_1_67_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp:75: ошибка: C2510: 'F': left
>   of '::' must be a class/struct/union
>   C:\Libs\boost_1_67_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp:75: ошибка: C3646: 'type':
>   unknown override specifier
>   C:\Libs\boost_1_67_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp:75: ошибка: C4430: missing
>   type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   C:\Libs\boost_1_67_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp:1284: ошибка: C2039: 'type':
>   is not a member of 'boost::_bi::result_traits' with [
>   R=boost::_bi::unspecified, F=void (__thiscall MyClass::* )(int,int) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в синтаксисе для использования указателя на нестатический метод класса. Запись `M T::*f` не позволяет объявить (и вывести тип) для такого указателя. Еще базовый класс тут ни к чему, а переданное в `connect` число никак не используется. Исправленный вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template< class A1, typename TF, typename... Args >
static auto make_bind( TF f, A1 a1, Args&& ...arg)
{
    return boost::bind(f, a1, boost::forward<Args>(arg)...);
}

template< class A1, typename TF, class B>
static boost::signals2::connection my_connect( TF f, A1 a1, B &connection, int num)
{
    return connection.connect(make_bind(f, a1, num, _1));
}

class OtherClass
{
public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> myConnection;
    void start() {
        myConnection(2);
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    void myFunc(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "hello " << a << " " << b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyClass *cl = new MyClass;
    OtherClass *myOtherClass = new OtherClass;

    my_connect(&MyClass::myFunc, cl, myOtherClass->myConnection, 1);

    myOtherClass->start();

    return 0;
}
```

А вообще вместо доп функций можно использовать лямду:

```
myOtherClass->myConnection.connect([cl, a{3}](int b){ cl->myFunc(a, b); });
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jgSWuU0V3ozYjNf0)

Если же хочется сделать функцию только для соединения без запоминания аргументов, то это тоже проще сделать при помощи лямбды:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template< class A1, class B, class TResult, class T, typename... TArgs>
static boost::signals2::connection my_connect(TResult ( T::* f )(TArgs...), A1 a1, B &connection)
{
    return connection.connect([f, a1](TArgs... args){ (a1->*f)(::boost::forward<TArgs>(args)...); });
}

class OtherClass
{
public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int, int)> myConnection;
    void start() {
        myConnection(1, 2);
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    void myFunc(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "hello " << a << " " << b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyClass *cl = new MyClass;
    OtherClass *myOtherClass = new OtherClass;

    my_connect(&MyClass::myFunc, cl, myOtherClass->myConnection);

    myOtherClass->start();

    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dbueBi1s35FzFKc9)

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, что я хотел. Я, наверное, плохо объяснил. Есть сигнал в одном классе, и функция в другом классе. Оба имеют одинаковый набор аргументов. Например: `boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> myConnection; void myFunc(int a) { std::cout << "hello " << a; }`. Нужно, чтобы была универсальная функция, чтобы соединить их. Таким образом, если бы я поменял сигнатуры сигнала и функции, соединение должно было бы опять сработать. В boost::bind нужно указать число аргументов при помощи перечисления _1,_2,_3 и так далее.

Comment: А в вашем коде число num передается как параметр, а я его хотел использовать для выбора нужного bind.                               
 `if (num == 1)
            return connection.connect(boost::bind(f, a1, _1)); 
        if (num == 2)
            return connection.connect(boost::bind(f, a1, _1, _2));`  и так далее

Comment: @soaup Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Вот это действительно то, что нужно! Огромное спасибо!